# Password disappears when sent by selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Ok, To start, Everything here is working. My issue right now is when the `password` sends the keys it disappears immediately. It's happening because the password input itself erases the password when you click the input again. My question is, is there a workaround to get the password injected without it disappearing?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from random import randint
import pickle
import datetime
import os
import time

url = 'https://sef.clareityiam.net/idp/login'

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
current_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get(url)
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))

user = driver.find_element_by_id("clareity")
user.send_keys("user")

password = driver.find_element_by_id("security")
password.send_keys("Password")


button = driver.find_element_by_id("loginbtn")
button.click()
```

Comment: there's nothing in the code you posted that clicks the input field after sending the keys.  Does it clear when clicking the submit button?  Maybe as a workaround try sending the enter key instead....

Comment: @pcalkins, it clears before even clicking the login btn.  It is strange.  I am looking at it now and have the login btn commented out. The text is just clearing for some reason

Answer (score 2):

Click this field before entering data. This works for me. Also, use at least implicit wait.
Another issue in your code may be that the id for password is not unique. There are two such locators.

```
import pickle
import time
from selenium import webdriver


url = 'https://sef.clareityiam.net/idp/login'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
user = driver.find_element_by_id("clareity")
user.send_keys("user")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-ph="PASSWORD"]')
password.click()
password.send_keys("Password")
time.sleep(6)  # Added temporary so you could see that password stays
button = driver.find_element_by_id("loginbtn")
button.click()
```

Comment: Deleted my reply, didn't see yours first.  Same workaround/solution :)

Comment: No problem, I upvote your answers sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to send keys in the input tag you can use the `execute_script` method with javascript. For example

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("security").setAttribute("value", "12345")')
```

Then you can submit this form by clicking on the button or submit via javascript like this

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("form").submit()')
```

Comment: have you actually tried this?  Nothing gets sent to the Password text box

Comment: I can't get access to this website. You can check if the input has value. You need to open the console and enter the following code `document.getElementById("security").value`. If it has the value it works, if it doesn't, you should look for another way

Answer (score 0):

I found somewhat of a work around for it. Idk why i didn't think about this while i was writing this script but.

if you send the passwords `send_keys` twice it stays. Don't understand why,  but it works.

Comment: I tried this but got a selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException